# What user to debug for public Communities access?

Tags: apex, community, debugging, lightning-community

I need to debug self-registration for a Salesforce Lightning Community, however since the user is not logged in yet (using self-registration code), I don't know which user to select for DEBUG.

Does anyone know which user to monitor? Or, how I might trace debug statements on a public (anonymous) Community?

Comment: The force.com sites connected with communities has a gues user, you can try monitoring with that user?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Setup --> Communities --> Workspace --> Administration --> Pages ---> Click on Site.com --> You would redirected to Site page related to community --> Click Public Access Setting --> You would redirected to Guest User Profile --> Click View All User--> You will get name/link of guest user.
2. Goto setup --> Debug Log --> and setup the debug for that guest user.
3. If you are using google chrome then open console (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and execute this line: document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";  (not needed after v41.0 but you can perform step this to be in just in case if still require.)

Comment: This does not work in a Lightning Community (API version 48). I can find the guest user `<community-name> Site Guest User` and have setup the Debug Log for him, but no debug logs are created.

Comment: Now, we do not need to setup anything in chrome. Just set a debug log for the guest users and it should work. Just verified before writing this comment. Make sure date range is the one in which you are testing. Also, if there are multiple sites/community, there will be different guest users.