# Community Self-Registration doesn't appear to be calling LightningSelfRegisterController

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, customer-community, lightning-community

I am trying to setup Community Self-Registration on a Lightning Community with a modification to use an existing account and contact vs creating a new contact and using the default account. After figuring out that `CommunitiesSelfRegController` is only used for classic Communities, I updated `LightningSelfRegisterController` in my dev environment and ran through the self-registration process while [debugging the guest access user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216527/what-user-to-debug-for-public-communities-access).

Oddly, `LightningSelfRegisterController` doesn't appear to be getting called (no debug statements in logs), even though I opened the `selfRegister` Lightning Component, which is the one used on the `/Register` page, and verified that `LightningSelfRegisterController` is the controller declared in the `<component/>` tag:

```
<aura:component controller="LightningSelfRegisterController">
```

Assuming that I still may not have setup the DEBUG log correctly, I even went as far as inserting `throw new CustomException()` statements in the controller method calls, but the self-registration page completely ignores it and just registers the user using the default process.

Do I need to tell Salesforce to use the customized `LightningSelfRegisterController` vs the standard process in same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Create a copy of selfRegister component

   - Just copy-paste the code
   - It's because selfRegister component appears only in Identity group and I couldn't re-use those components on my custom pages
   - I was using Build Your Own Template and had to create another Customer Service (Napili) theme to get `selfRegister` and `LightningSelfRegisterController`
2. Change a name of the new component in design bundle (.design file)
3. Create a new public page that will contain your new component
4. Update self-registration setting to point to your new registration page

   - Setup > All Communities > Workspaces > Administration > Registration > Community Builder Page: New Register Page
5. Setup logs for a Guest User

   - Put `Site` In Lookup field, when setting the trace, to show all community Guest Users
6. In an anonymous window open your community page, click Sign Up

   - You should be redirected to your new Registration page
7. Now you should be seeing full debug logs

---

To me, it looks like Login Pages / Identity Components (Self Registration, Change Password, Login Form, ...) have debug logs turned off by design.

Comment: Thanks @Michal, I was able to get it to work with this approach. Curious to know if you ran in to minor styling issues on form fields/button when you copied the existing component? Also, designer attribute names are strange too.

Comment: @SwisherSweet If I remember correctly copied component wasn't exactly the same as the one from Idenity Components section. I was doing custom registration form I had no styling issues. If you could be more specific I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out they are not the same as well, so corrected the styling manually using CSS. Thanks again!